# How to install Internet Explorer in Ubuntu?

Tags: internet-explorer, ubuntu

I have struggled in installing Internet Explorer in Ubuntu. Can anyone help me to do?

Comment: Why do you want to use the internet explorer?

Comment: Apart from the question being off topic, IE is not available on Unix/Linux platforms.

Comment: There are still quite a few things that will only run on IE so it is a valid question.

Comment: Off-topic here - try http://askubuntu.com

Comment: @Oded: You can install it. This belongs on AskUbuntu, though. (A simple Google search will shed some light as well)

Comment: http://www.upubuntu.com/2011/10/how-to-install-and-run-internet.html

Comment: @ThatOtherPerson - WINE is not Ubuntu...

Comment: @Oded: The OP was asking, specifically, how to do it in Ubuntu.

Answer (score 2):

You need to emulate windows : http://www.winehq.org/download/ubuntu

Or use chrome, or firefox, or opera. Which is what I think what most people would do.

Comment: W.I.N.E. = Wine is **not** an emulator.

Comment: Wine is a compatibility layer - it just provides *nix versions of the Windows APIs